# How do I access the images in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my sample project for the previous rails versions I would access the images as

```
<%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %>
```

How can I do the same in rails 3.1 since the images folder has been moved to `app/assets/` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Links like this:

```
<img src="/images/my-image.jpg" />
```

become:

```
<img src="/assets/my-image.jpg" />
```

Rails does some magic to figure out that it's actually in the images directory. So no need to specify the images directory.